# HTML not showing up in view page source

Tags: php, html

**Summary:** designing a file management system for school, currently working on the page that will display a list of downloads in an HTML table

**Problem:** Nothing is showing up on the browser when pull up the page that I put onto my website. When I check view page source nothing is listed. Somehow none of my HTML is getting recognized and I'm not sure why.

When I moved my HTML opening tag above the php statement it was the only thing that showed up on the view page source..what am I doing wrong here?

**Update: I commented out the php at the top of my `download_list.php` file and my HTML displayed. So something is clearly wrong with my php.

**The code:**

**download_list.php :**

```
    ini_set( 'display_errors', TRUE );
    error_reporting( E_ALL);

    require_once('database.php');

    // Get all categories
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM file
              ORDER BY fileID';
    $files = $db->query($query);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!-- the head section -->
<head>
    <title>My Downloads</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" /> 
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

            <h1>Category List</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($files as $file) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $file['filename']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <form action="download_file.php" method="post"
                        id="download_file_form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="category_id"
                               value="<?php echo $file['filename']; ?>"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Download"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <br />

    <h2>Add Category</h2>
    <form action="add_category.php" method="post"
          id="add_category_form">

        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="input" name="name" />
        <input id="add_category_button" type="submit" value="Add"/>
    </form>
    <br />
    <p><a href="index.php">List Products</a></p>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**database.php :**

```
<?php


    mysql_connect("filler.hostica.com", "filler", "filler") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("filler") or die(mysql_error());

    exit();

?>
```

Comment: There's probably an error in your PHP. More specifically, it's either `require_once('database.php');` or `$files = $db->query($query);`.

Comment: Generally this is symptomatic of a parse error or other PHP failure. Try using `php <file.php>` or viewing your server's error logs to see what the problem is.

Comment: As others mentioned, something wrong in your php code, check your code in database.php. make sure error reporting is set to E_ALL

Comment: can you show what is in your database.php ?

Comment: displayed it in the question, however I did find that once I commented out my php code at the top of download_list.php my HTML displayed. So must be error in that top php block.

Comment: Are you sure the `$files` is not NULL?

Comment: no, what is the most effective way to check?

Comment: [`exit();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) will end your script and nothing else will be displayed

Comment: also you are calling to a class `$db->query()`, but that class is not in `database.php`

Comment: @Sean you're absolutely right..this was very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database.php probably shouldn't call `exit();`

Edit: From Sean's comment: also you are calling to a class $db->query(), but that class is not in database.php

Comment: Nice pick-up. For the OP, `require()` and `include()` are essentially saying "*Get this file, and insert/execute its contents here.*". So, having `exit()` or `die()` in the included/required file will execute it and terminate the script then and there.

Comment: @emartel please add Sean's comment to your answer for a complete solution to this issue for sake of readers: `also you are calling to a class $db->query(), but that class is not in database.php`

Answer (score 1):

Remove or comment `exit();` in database.php.